# ¿Como llamar un metodo que pertenece a otra clase? JAVA POO

Tags: java, poo, método

Holaa , estoy haciendo un programa sobre el peso de las personas y debo hacer varios metodos uno de ellos es  : promedioPeso que esta en la clase EstadisticasDePersonas pero mi problema es que no se como llamar a una variable o al metodo getPeso() que es de la clase Persona para calcularlo , ya que si pongo solo getPeso() me sale error en eclipse y me dice que debo crear ese metodo dentro de la clase EstadisticasDePersonas pero yo quiero llamarlo desde la clase Persona por que como ya lo hice ahi , para que voy a crear de nuevo el mismo en otra clase ... por ahora llegue hasta aca :

```
public class Persona {

private String nombre ;
private int edad;
private double peso;
private String genero ;
private double altura;

public Persona(String nombre , int edad , double peso , String genero , double altura) {

    this.nombre = nombre ;
    this.edad = edad ;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.genero = genero;
    this.altura = altura;

}

public String toString() {
    return "EstadisticasDePersonas [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", peso=" + peso + ", genero=" + genero
            + ", altura=" + altura + "]";
}



public String getNombre () {

    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre (String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad () {

    return this.edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {

    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getPeso() {

    return this.peso ;
}

public void setPeso() {

    this.peso = peso;
}

public String getGenero() {

    return this.genero;
}

public void setGenero (String genero) {

    this.genero = genero;
}

public double getAltura() {

    return this.altura;
}

public void setAltura() {

    this.altura = altura;
}
```

}

```
public class EstadisticasDePersonas {

private String nombre ;


public EstadisticasDePersonas (String nombre) {
    this.nombre =nombre;

}


public double pesoPromedio() {

    int contadorPeso=0;
    int sumatoriaPeso =0;
    double pesoPromedio=0.0;

    if (getPeso()>0) {

        contadorPeso++; 
    }

    sumatoriaPeso+=contadorPeso;
    pesoPromedio= sumatoriaPeso/50;

    return pesoPromedio;

}
```

Comment: un consejo dado a como veo que todas tus preguntas en en general son de Conseptos muy basicos. y en mi opinion creo que a punta de preguntas y respuestas, si bien aprenderas, no creo que apendas todos los conseptos ni de la mejor forma por tanto te aconsejo Leer un libro de Programacion [por ejemplo este](https://openlibra.com/es/book/introduccion-a-la-programacion-orientada-a-objetos-con-java) y/o leer los tutoriales de Oracle [enlace de oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Un método regular no lo llamas en la *clase* Persona, lo llamas sobre un objeto de la clase persona, técnicamente hablando, sobre una *instancia* de la clase<sup>1</sup>.

Esto, si lo piensas, tiene mucho sentido. La *clase* es como el *molde* con el que se representa y se *construye* una persona. Pero no hay un *peso* de todas las personas, sino que cada persona tiene su propio peso.

Entonces, si necesitas el peso de una persona particular, primero has de haber construido un objeto -una instancia- de esa clase, y luego puedes establecer y obtener su peso.

Vamos a hacer un pequeño ejemplo:

```
{
  //declaramos una _variable_ para una persona
  Persona juan;
  //ahora, creamos el objeto y lo inicializamos...
  juan = new Persona();
  juan.setNombre("Juan Antonio");
  juan.setEdad(43);
  juan.setPeso(125.12);
  //.... hacemos otras cosas
  //y ahora, recuperamos el peso
  double peso;
  peso = juan.getPeso();
}
```

Ahora, suponiendo que tienes esta clase `EstadisticasDePersonas`, no me queda muy claro su uso o su objetivo, pero podría ser que esta clase tuviera una lista de personas que se van agregando y luego podemos obtener el peso de cualquiera de estas personas.  Acá voy a asumir, que internamente la clase tiene una lista o un arreglo de personas y que tiene un método `agregarPersona(Persona persona)` que va añadiendo personas a este arreglo o lista, por ejemplo, puedo hacer algo como esto:

```
{
  Persona juan;
  Persona mario;
  EstadisticaPersonas estadistica;
  estadistica = new EstadisticaPersonas();

  juan = new Persona();
  juan.setNombre("Juan Antonio");
  juan.setEdad(43);
  juan.setPeso(125.12);
  estadistica.agregarPersona(juan);

  mario = new Persona();
  mario.setNombre("Mario Alberto");
  mario.setEdad(44);
  mario.setPeso(132.15);
  estadistica.agregarPersona(mario);
  }
```

Entonces, dentro de esta clase, podrías implementar el método getPesoPromedio, valiéndote de un `foreach` haciendo algo como:

```
public double getPesoPromedio() {

    int cantidadPersonas = 0;
    double sumatoriaPeso = 0;

    for (Persona persona : listaPersonas) {
      cantidadPersonas++;
      sumatoriaPeso += persona.getPeso();
    }

    return sumatoriaPeso / cantidadPersonas;
}
```

claro, acá ya estamos en el terreno de las suposiciones y voy a detenerme... espero que la información vertida ayude a aclarar tus dudas.

---

<sup>1</sup>: He dicho que generalmente se llama sobre un objeto, pero java (y muchos otros lenguajes orientados a objetos) si que permiten llamar a un método sobre una clase, pero este es un tipo especial, o menos común, de método, que se llama *método estático* o *método de clase*. Este método se llama sobre la clase, pero como tal, está en un contexto distinto y no tiene acceso a los miembros o métodos regulares de la clase, que siempre requieren de una instancia para ser accedidos/invocados.

Comment: seria bueno agregar la documentacion y enlaces como este: [tutorial de Oracle sobre Objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)  nota estan en ingles...

y sobre la magia de ["Static"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas acceder a los métodos y propiedades que existen en el archivoA.java pero desde el archivoB.java; debes considerar lo siguiente

1. Ambos deben estar dentro del mismo `package`
2. Necesitas realizar el proceso de instanciación en el archivoB.java para darle a un objeto el acceso a los métodos de archivoA.java
3. Considera que en Persona.java tienes un constructor que inicializa una serie de propiedades cuando la clase es creada; entonces al momento de realizar la instanción, necesitas asignarle por cada propiedad pasada al constructor sus correspondientes valores
4. Nota que ambos archivos los puse en el mismo package llamado `stackover` con lo cual desde un archivo al intentar acceder a los valores de otro, lo realizará siempre y cuando estén dentro del mismo antes mencionado

**Persona.java**

```
package stackover;

public class Persona {

private String nombre ;
private int edad;
private double peso;
private String genero ;
private double altura;

public Persona(String nombre , int edad , double peso , String genero , double altura) {

    this.nombre = nombre ;
    this.edad = edad ;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.genero = genero;
    this.altura = altura;

}

public String toString() {
    return "EstadisticasDePersonas [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", peso=" + peso + ", genero=" + genero
            + ", altura=" + altura + "]";
}



public String getNombre () {

    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre (String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad () {

    return this.edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {

    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getPeso() {

    return this.peso ;
}

public void setPeso() {

    this.peso = peso;
}

public String getGenero() {

    return this.genero;
}

public void setGenero (String genero) {

    this.genero = genero;
}

public double getAltura() {

    return this.altura;
}

public void setAltura() {

    this.altura = altura;
}
}
```

**EstadisticasDePersonas.java**

```
package stackover;

public class EstadisticasDePersonas
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Persona personita = new Persona("Alfredo", 23, 23.2, "masculino", 12.3);
        personita.setGenero("Femenino");
        personita.getGenero();

    }
}
```