# Quisiera hacer llamada de un desde una clase A, a un metodo de una clase B

Tags: java

Necesito llamar desde el main a un metodo de una clase b, pero este metodo que se encuentra en b, contiene metodos de otras clases, como podría hacerlo. Si es necesario subo las clases con su codigo si hiciera falta para comprenderlo.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: crea un objeto de la clase b en el main de la clase a y así podrás usar sus métodos, de no entenderlo copia y pega tu código..saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como llamar un metodo que pertenece a otra clase? JAVA POO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220303/como-llamar-un-metodo-que-pertenece-a-otra-clase-java-poo)

Answer (score 0):

para invocar a un método de una clase primero debes saber si ese método es estático o de instancia. Si es estático existe solo uno por clase. Este tipo de métodos los usas  cuando no importa la instancia que lo ejecute.
Si quieres ejecutar un metodo estatico lo haces con el nombre de la clase con Mayúscula punto y el nombre del metodo. Ej: `Banco.getTotalClientes();`
En cambio si es un método de instancia, debes crear una instancia de esa clase primero y invocar al método sobre esa instancia. Ej:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.setLimiteCredito(1000);
```

Como puedes ver el límite se ejecuta sobre esa instancia específica. No sobre toda la clase por eso es un método de instancia. Mientras en el primer ejemplo no hay ninguna instancia sobre la que se ejecuta sino sobre toda la clase.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   //invocar un metodo estatico desde el main
   Banco.getTotalClientes();

   //invocar metodo de instancia
   Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
   cliente.setLimiteCredito(1000);
}
```